# When uploading file via ajax, it always returns [ as file info

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have looked through many different questions and I still haven't been able to locate the flaw in my code. I basically  am attempting to upload a file to the server using html/ajax and php for the server side. Below is my code:

```
 //HTML
<div class="col-sm-6">
  <div class="">
     <input name="bugType" type="text" class="bugType">
  </div>
 </div>
 <div class="col-sm-6">
    <div class="upload">
       <input name="bugImage" type="file" class="bugImage">
    </div>
 </div>

//JS 
$("#addBug").on('click', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var bugType = $('input[name="bugType"]').val();
    var imageName = $('input[name="bugImage"]');
    fd = new FormData();
    fd.append("type", "add");
    fd.append("imageName", imageName);
    fd.append("bugType", bugType);
    $.ajax({
        url: 'classes/bug-class.php',
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "json",
        data: fd ,
        enctype: 'multipart/form-data',
        contentType: false, 
        processData: false,  
        success: function (data) {
            alert("SUCCESS");
            alert(data);
        },
        error: function (data) {
            alert("FAILURE");
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
});



//PHP
$type = $_POST['bugType'];
$image = $_POST['imageName'][0];
echo $image; //PRINTS OUT [
```

If I change:

```
  $image = $_FILES['imageName']
  echo $image // PRINTS OUT ""
```

Thanks for the help!

//EDIT

```
 FileList {0: File, length: 1}
 0
 :
 File
 lastModified
 :
 1475177716000
 lastModifiedDate
 :
 Thu Sep 29 2016 14:35:16 GMT-0500 (CDT)
 name
 :
 "17-3.png"
 size
 :
 187682
 type
:
"image/png"
webkitRelativePath
:
```

""
   **proto**
   :
   File
  length
  :
   1
   **proto**
  :
  FileList

```
var_dump($_FILES) // output -> array(0)
```

//WORKING

had to change to this:

```
  fd.append("imageName", imageName[0])
```

and then it worked!

Comment: try `console.log(fd)` and post the output.

Comment: `$('input[name="bugImage"]')[0].files`

Comment: @KarthikeyanSekar It now sends the file and I get on the php side: object fileList ... however when I try to access it like normal, get the same thing

Comment: `$_FILES['bugImage']['name']` try this http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You directly send the element to your `SERVER`.

```
var imageName = $('input[name="bugImage"]');


var imageName = $('input[name="bugImage"]')[0].files;
```

Comment: Okay and what would the php side of this be...shouldn't it be the standard 

$image = $_FILES['imageName

Comment: $_FILES['bugImage']['name'] try this  http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: hmmm... I went ahead and tried that and it output ""

Comment: I actually get: Undefined index: imageName  ... which means it must not be pushing it correctly

Comment: when I var_dump($_FILES) i get array(0)... but I do get an object filelist which should show up in the $_FILES list to my understanding

Comment: PHP SERVER doesn't know your `element`

Comment: FileList {0: File, length: 1}
0
:
File
lastModified
:
1475177716000
lastModifiedDate
:
Thu Sep 29 2016 14:35:16 GMT-0500 (CDT)
name
:
"17-3.png"
size
:
187682
type
:
"image/png"
webkitRelativePath
:
""
__proto__
:
File
length
:
1
__proto__
:
FileList

Is the fileList being passed through the fd.append("imageName", imageName);

Comment: had to send fd.append("imageName", imageName[0]) and then  it worked!